# Spastic img results on element.html() call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, image, src

There are 2 components to understand for this question

### Statement of Issue

**GetProdImage.cs**

```
   //Retrieves image from db based on id
    int id = Page.RouteData.Values["prod_id"];
    Controller controller = new Controller();

    DBContext context = GetDBContext();

    ProductImage productImage = controller.GetImage(id);

    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/"+productImage.ImageExt;
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(productImage.bindata);
    context.Response.Flush();
```

**JQuery HTML build**

```
<script>
                function ihatemylife()
                {
                    debugger;
                    var html = "<img src=\"http://localhost:3756/GetProdImage/10\" style=\"max-width: 200px;\"/>" +
                     "<img src=\"http://localhost:3756/GetProdImage/11\" style=\"max-width: 200px;\"/>" +
                    " <img src=\"http://localhost:3756/GetProdImage/12\" style=\"max-width: 200px;\"/>";

                    $("#sm-test").html(html);
                }

                });
    </script>
        <div id="sm-test"></div>
```

Note that each image is just a red number.
It is inserted to the a DOM element using the standard

```
$(element).html(html);
```

This build produces this:
Each column is a page refresh.
Note how the order is never the same.
[image]

Inspect the page (proving the html is correct)

[image]

### Debugging Info

If a breakpoint is placed in the GetProdImage.cs you can see that it is called when the html is inserted. The weird thing is that the value of id is reflective of the spastic image ordering, not of what is reflected in the html.
i.e. First iteration GetProdImage is called with 12, 10, 12
Second iteration it's called with 11,12, 12 etc

This observation made me think it is an issue with my implementation of jQuery.

If each url of the GetProdImage is visited it WILL produce the correct image.

[image]

So to test that:

If I cut out the GetProdImage() all together and use hard coded img src values to public images, like so:

```
    html += "<td><img title=\"" + i + "\" src=\"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d0/DJCTQ_-_10.JPG\" />" +
"<img title=\"" + i + "\" src=\"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/French_Military_Button_Rgmt_Number_11.jpg\"/>" +  " <img title=\"" + i + "\" src=\"http://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/569284/257460898/stock-photo-number-257460898.jpg\""/></td>";
```

The result is a surprising:
With the images being in the correct order every time.
[image]

I believe that my contradiction is now clear.

**Debugging from Comments**
1)  tags placed directly on the page, not loaded thru the jquery call using the GetProdImage as src work correctly every time.

2) Turing EnableSessionState="false" for the page where the jquery is called had no effect.

### Question

What would cause the behavior of the GetProdImage to be receiving (and returning) images in a random order?
The received random numbers points to JQuery being at fault.
The hard coded img src points to GetProdImage.

I'm dumb.

These are my issues.

Comment: jQuery is just setting the html code, your backend is the one producing the actual image content. Problem probably lies in your backend. `Page.RouteData.Values["prod_id"]` not actually getting the correct id, or `controller.GetImage(id)` not retrieving your image data correctly

Comment: @PatrickEvans edited, added image to show that GetProdImage does function correctly.

Comment: What happens when you hard code img html? ie `<td><img src=".../GetProdImage/10"><img src=".../GetProdImage/11"><img src=".../GetProdImage/12"></td>`? Does it show in the correct order?

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes, if the <img> tags are put right on the page, not thru the jquery call, they appear in order.

Comment: Do you use session on all that calls ?, if yes. disables it for that page and call, and if works correct I will explain it with more details...

Comment: @Aristos could you elaborate a bit? The page where the jquery is called does have EnableSessionState="true" set at the Page level, needed for authorization purposes.

Comment: @hogarth45 make a test and disable it for see if works well...

Comment: @hogarth45 Ok then this is not the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was here
GetProdImage.cs

```
int id = Page.RouteData.Values["prod_id"];
```

There was a race condition happening for the id to be set.
I altered it to be HttpContext driven instead of REST.